# Python: What's best practice for variable initialization value that won't render True or False when used in boolean logic?

Tags: python, oop, initialization, boolean, boolean-expression

I often times find myself initializing an attribute in a class to False, But what I really want is for this to represent True or False ONLY after it is actually assigned to reduce bugs in the future. For instance, the attribute isDog I want to assign later in the methods to either True or False, but I hate having to assign the default to "False" since it leaves room for bugs in the future and seems to assume a priori it's not a dog. Is there a best practice or standard for what I could assign this to that won't render in boolean logic (instead, printing an error if used in Boolean logic) so that I don't need to preassign as False?

Comment: Could we see some example code?  Frequently the answer to this is to simply not initialize the variable until you have a value for it, and use static analysis to make sure you don't have a code path where you could ever refer to the variable before it's been initialized.  It's impossible to demonstrate without seeing an example of what you're working on, though.

Comment: I agree with @Samwise, but I advice you to use `isDog=None`

Comment: @NicolòTeseo, that might also evaluate to `False` a lot of times

Comment: only problem with `isDog = None` is that unless you're very careful in the rest of your code to check for `None` values explicitly (e.g. you're only using `isDog` as an argument to functions that explicitly take a `bool`, and you're using a static typechecker), it'll just get treated as a `False` anyway.

Comment: @Samwise Exactly. That's my issue with using "None".

Comment: @Prospero show us your code!

Comment: @Samwise I don't have any example code for this specifically because I can't release code given this is for work. But do you understand the situation? I noticed you said "not to initialize at all", but how does one accomplish this? If I just do "self.isDog" (without any assignment operator after) then it outputs an error as this variable never having existed.

Comment: Select the `self.isDog = False` line which initializes the variable to False before you actually know whether the thing is a dog (the entire thing, not just the `= False` part) and push the Delete key.  If that's unclear, or it doesn't fix your problem, come up with a MRE that doesn't include anything proprietary, and add it to your question.  That way people can give you an answer in the form of code changes that work within the context of your MRE, and you can extrapolate that to your real code.

Comment: What about a class attribute: `isDog = False`? This will give all instances this attribute (with the same caveats you mention in your question) without being mentioned in the `__init__()` and any subsequent: `self.isDog = <value>` makes it an instance variable at that point.

Answer (score 0):

A good option is to define your variable as `None` and check if it is defined before using it.

Here an example:

```py
class Animal:
    def __init__(self):
        self.is_dog: Optional[bool] = None
        ...

    def become_a_dog(self) -> None:
        self.is_dog = True

    def become_a_cat(self) -> None:
        self.is_dog = False

    def can_bark(self) -> bool:
        if self.is_dog is None:
            raise Exception("Animal instance is not yet specified as dog or cat.")
        return self.is_dog
```

Comment: While this works, it's clear (to me) in this instance that the class should just be redesigned such that `is_dog` is an argument to `__init__` rather than being set after the fact.  And it depends on remembering to explicitly check `is_dog` in every method, and possibly in every user of this class.  Maybe it'd be better to wrap it in a `@property` that raises the exception -- but then you might as well just not define the attribute in `__init__` at all and let it raise `AttributeError` if it's unset!

Answer (score 0):

I won't say that this is best practice or standard, however you could use the None keyword to achieve this functionality.

Take a look at the code example below

```
class Pet:
  def __init__(self):
    self.isDog = None
    self.isCat = None

myCat = Pet()
myCat.isCat = True

if myCat.isDog:
  print('I have a dog!')

if myCat.isCat:
  print('I have a cat!')

if myCat.isDog == None:
  print("I haven't decided whether it's a dog yet")
```

This code will output "I have a cat!", and "I haven't decided whether it's a dog yet"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround using `@property`

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._is_foo = None
        
    @property
    def is_foo(self):
        assert isinstance(self._is_foo, bool), "ERROR!!!"
        return self._is_foo
        
    def set_foo(self, val):
        self._is_foo = val
        
x = Foo()
x.is_foo
# AssertionError: ERROR!!!

x.set_foo(True)
x.is_foo
# True
```

Comment: Why is this better than just deleting the `__init__` and having a regular old `self.is_foo` attribute that doesn't exist at all until you set it explicitly?  That would be much simpler and you'd get a more useful exception (an `AttributeError`) if you try to access `is_foo` before it's been set.

Comment: The only reason to define the attributes in the beginning is to eliminate the possibility of a code path where you raise an exception because you accessed one before it was initialized.  Having a property that raises an exception if the underlying attribute hasn't been explicitly initialized is just recreating that behavior (i.e. the behavior that ordinarily you'd be trying to avoid by initializing everything in `__init__`) with a lot of extra steps.

Comment: From the POV of readability/maintainability this whole delayed initialization pattern should be avoided entirely, but if we had to use it then from a readability standpoint I'd rather just see a single line comment and/or docstring in `__init__` (calling out the uninitialized `self.is_foo` and the need to `set_foo()` before actually using the instance) than have five extra lines of code you have to read in their entirety to understand the pitfall -- especially in a large class that maybe has a bunch of other stuff going on!  :)

Comment: @Samwise, I am trying to avoid setting attributes later that hasn't been already defined in the `__init__`.